# Invalid thread access when calling an instance of a class

Tags: java, class

Im trying to make an application that connects to a server trough ssh (jsch) and runs a few commands.
I use the gui so the user can imput the info needed and when clicking the button then the application runs the commands.

The conection and the commands are handled by a class I created.

The problem is that when i create an instance of this class on the main I get the Invalid thread access error.

Any ideas??

Comment: Post the full stack trace of the exception, and the relevant code. We are not extra-lucid wizards.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error 'cause it's not allowed to operate SWT components from threads other than SWT Display thread. You can run any code on the display thread explicitly with this trick:

```
Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // create gui here
    }
});
```